# How does a C compiler know how to store the addresses of a 2D array?

Tags: c, gcc

Consider your typical gcc compiler (C99 mode) and consider an array:

```
char array[2][4];
```

clearly the compiler would compile (I assume it's in the translation process?) the code to make the target machine (let's suppose it's an X86) work in the way that it "settles", or shall we say, "assigns" both addresses of array[0][0] and array[1][0] before accessing either one of them (I could be completely wrong). My problem is how does the compiler "know" this, since it is just a dumb program? Is it a simple recursion algorithm of some sort done amazingly right so we don't really have to care how many dimensions there ever will be (as in "oh, there's a bracket pair following the name "array"? I'll just translate it into an address, wait, there are 2? Address of an address then) or those people who designed the compiler specifically studied the situation and coded the compiler to tackle it?

If you were confused by my question, consider an one dimensional array arr[2].
I can get arr involved in all sorts of calculation knowing it's just an address, a "beginning address" so to speak. But for a 1D array, you only need one "beginning address" which is easily accomplished during compilation since the compiler will just translate that name (in this case, arr) into an uninitialized address (again, I could be completely wrong), but for a 2D array, the compiler need to deal with more than one address, how does it work?

And what would the assembly code look like?

Comment: Actually `char array[M][N];` is a sequential block of memory (i.e. 1D) that the language (and thus the parser/lexer) treats as 2D. The 2D is simply syntactic sugar helping you with the memory stride.

Comment: Try multiplying the indices of the multi-dimension array

Comment: I have to say, I don't understand the amount of downvotes here.. even though it might look trivial after a few years working with C

Comment: Your question is basically a special case of "how does a compiler do stuff with variables?".  It's unclear what you mean by "dumb program" - clearly a compiler is sophisticated enough to do exactly what's required to implement this aspect (and many other aspects) of the C programming language.

Comment: @grek40: This question would be a lot better if it just asked "How are addresses calculated for a 2D array?".  As it stands, it's meandering and difficult to know exactly what's being asked (at face value).

Comment: @grek40 Yes; imagine your grandmother trying to learn this. The amount of information in the sphere of computer programming is overwhelming, and newcomers have to approach concepts in strange non-linear ways due to the way the brain must form hypotheses to fill in the gaps over unfamiliar ground.

Comment: @Kaz My grandma started using mails a few years ago, she is quite happy with it. No need to drag her into some compiler-internals discussion :). [Off-Topic closed]

Answer (score 6):

A 2D array such as

```
int arr[3][2] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}};
```

is laid out in memory as:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

because C is a [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) language.

This is the same layout as:

```
int arrflat[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

And you can access and manipulate both arrays using just their address (`arr` and `arrflat`, respectively).

However, when you access elements via `arr[y][x]` or `arrflat[i]` a translation occurs.

`arrflat[i]` becomes

```
arrflat+i
```

whereas `arr[y][x]` becomes

```
arr+(y*width+x)
```

and, in fact, you can do pointer mathematics on `arr` in this way.

A simple test program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int arr[3][2]  = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}};
  int arrflat[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

  for(int y=0;y<3;y++)
  for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
    printf("%d\n",arr[y][x]);

  for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    printf("%d\n",arrflat[i]);
}
```

Compile this to generate assembly with

```
gcc -g -Wa,-adhls  test.c
```

The (abbreviated) output is:

```
 9:test.c        ****     printf("%d\n",arr[y][x]);
49                  .loc 1 9 0 discriminator 3
50 007d 8B45B8      movl  -72(%rbp), %eax
51 0080 4898        cltq
52 0082 8B55B4      movl  -76(%rbp), %edx
53 0085 4863D2      movslq  %edx, %rdx
54 0088 4801D2      addq  %rdx, %rdx
55 008b 4801D0      addq  %rdx, %rax
56 008e 8B4485C0    movl  -64(%rbp,%rax,4), %eax
57 0092 89C6        movl  %eax, %esi
58 0094 BF000000    movl  $.LC0, %edi
58      00
59 0099 B8000000    movl  $0, %eax
59      00
60 009e E8000000    call  printf

12:test.c        ****     printf("%d\n",arrflat[i]);
80                  .loc 1 12 0 discriminator 3
81 00c0 8B45BC      movl  -68(%rbp), %eax
82 00c3 4898        cltq
83 00c5 8B4485E0    movl  -32(%rbp,%rax,4), %eax
84 00c9 89C6        movl  %eax, %esi
85 00cb BF000000    movl  $.LC0, %edi
85      00
86 00d0 B8000000    movl  $0, %eax
86      00
87 00d5 E8000000    call  printf
```

Eliminating common code between the two calls to `printf` and annotating gives:

```
 9:test.c        ****     printf("%d\n",arr[y][x]);
49                  .loc 1 9 0 discriminator 3
50 007d 8B45B8      movl  -72(%rbp), %eax        #Load address -72 bytes from the memory pointed to by %rbp
51 0080 4898        cltq                         #Turn this into a 64-bit integer address (where is `arr`?)
52 0082 8B55B4      movl  -76(%rbp), %edx        #Load address -76 bytes from the memory pointed to by %rbp
53 0085 4863D2      movslq  %edx, %rdx           #Turn %edx into a signed 64-bit offset
54 0088 4801D2      addq  %rdx, %rdx             #Add rdx to itself
55 008b 4801D0      addq  %rdx, %rax             #Add offset to the address
56 008e 8B4485C0    movl  -64(%rbp,%rax,4), %eax #Load *(rbp - 4 + (rax * 4)) into eax (get arr[y][x])

12:test.c        ****     printf("%d\n",arrflat[i]);
80                  .loc 1 12 0 discriminator 3
81 00c0 8B45BC      movl  -68(%rbp), %eax        #Load address -62 bytes from the memory pointed to by %rbp
82 00c3 4898        cltq                         #Convert this into a 64-bit integer address (where is `arrflat`?)
83 00c5 8B4485E0    movl  -32(%rbp,%rax,4), %eax #Load *(rbp - 4 + (rax * 4)) into eax (get arrflat[i])
```

Comment: You should specify that in `arr+(y*width+x)` you're treating `arr` as a simple (element) address as one might confuse it with C code. In code it actually translates to `(int*)((uintptr)arr + (y*width + x) * sizeof(int))`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is linearization (or serialization if you prefer). Machine memory is usually flat 1D space, and this is largely sufficient provided that what you need can be embedded into it. In your case, for example, a 2D array is just a way to interpret a 1D array sequencing.

If you have a 2x3 square array, this is reducible to a 6 linear array: map [0][0] to [0], [0][1] to [1], [O][2] to [2], [1][0] to [3], [1][1] to [4] and [1][2] to [5]. This mapping is really obvious as it maps [x][y] to [x*3+y] (remember that 3 is the size of the second dimension of you 2x3 2D array). In general for any 2D array of size NxM the mapping is x*M+y. Now for greater dimension, it works as well... So you just need the *beginning* address to store any kind of object and computes the right offset from it.

Answer (score 0):

- C does not have multidimensional arrays. Multidimensional arrays are simulated by declaring arrays of arrays, which is what the declaration `char a[2][2]` is doing.
- An array doesn't have multiple addresses; it has just one base address. The addresses of the elements are calculated by displacement ("pointer arithmetic"). C in fact defines the `A[B]` notation to be equivalent to `*(A + B)` in every way including the commutativity implied by the `+` operator.
- Apparent multi-dimensional references are just cascaded application of the above: `A[B][C]` is just `*(A[B] + C)` which is `*(*(A + B) + C)`. Here `A[B]` is expected to designate an array (or a pointer). If the subexpression `A[B]` refers to an array, then the value it produces is a pointer to the first element. The `+ C` then simply performs another round of pointer arithmetic to displace relative to that element; i.e., calculating an offset within the second-level array, completing the illusion that `A[B][C]` is a multi-dimensional array referencing notation.
- The address of an array isn't stored (as a pointer). If an array is defined at file scope, then its storage is associated with an internal or external symbol. If an array is defined as a nonstatic local variable, the compiler will typically arrange for a region of storage on the stack corresponding to that array's size and the generated code will refer to its base address using a fixed offset from the stack pointer. An array defined inside a struct is just a reserved block of space inside the struct, with a fixed offset from the base address of the struct.

Answer (score -1):

[Lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) is the process you're looking for. It turns a sequence of characters into tokens, a 2D array is one of those tokens.

In the case of an array the compiler will know to put aside that much memory for each token.

Comment: I think the OP was asking for how compiler handles 1D and 2D array. Lexical analysis is a step but it does not answer OP's question fully.